# Populating AngularJS Form from multiple data sources

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller that returns a person data (name, id, date-of-birth, etc.) as individual fields, and I have an angular form that displays this data and allows to edit it, so far so good.

The problem is that one of the fields is a "country", and I want to include a drop down combo with all the countries for the end user to pick one.

How do I populate that combo with all the countries? shall I provide all the countries from the same controller that returns the person's data? or shall I have a separate controller that returns the list of all countries and somehow link the person's country field to the complete list of countries returned by the other controller?

Comment: Countries should come from a from an Angular factory/service. Then call this factory from within your controller.

Comment: Expanding on @Bonatoc said, just add your `user` and `country` to the scope of the form, each one taken from where they need to be taken from.

Comment: Help yourself : https://gist.github.com/Keeguon/2310008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question of architecture.  And it depends.  If you want to populate the form from two separate calls that can be accomplished.  If you want to populate it from a single call that's not a problem either.  It's really a subjective choice.  If you want to use two calls you can do this:

```
app.controller('PersonController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.loadPerson = function() {
        $http.get('/person', { params: { personId: personId } } ).success( function( result ) {
            if( result.success ) {
                $scope.person = result.person;
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.loadCountries = function() {
        $http.get('/countries').success( function( result ) {
            if( result.success ) {
               $scope.countries = result.countries;
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.loadPerson();
    $scope.loadCountries();
};
```

And the view:

```
<html>
   <body>
       <form ...>
          <label>Name</label>
          <input ng-model="person.name"/>
          <label>Country</label>
          <select ng-selected="person.country" ng-options="country.name for country in counties"></select>
       </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now should you do this?  Well it increases the number of calls going to the server.  Probably not a big deal if it's just these two.  However, as a general rule if you can reduce your roundtrips that will make your site perform faster.  And your choices of countries will arrive when your person object arrives.  That reduces the issues from one arriving before the other.  The good news is that angular handles the normal issues that would arise from out of order data.  It goes from major issue to minor glitch.  Of these issues round trips are the most significant.

Separating these calls allows it to easier to reuse calls across multiple forms.  Sometimes it's easier just to break out the calls and make multiple round trips because it's tedious to put extra data into every call.  But the bigger reason to separate them is it's easier to cache countries across multiple forms in an angular service.  That's probably the main reason to separate them is you can call countries once and cache it client side.  Then make several calls over to pull down different people without incurring the transfer of countries multiple times.  In the end that makes it less data between lots of calls while taking a minor hit to make extra round trip at the beginning.